# Need help in understanding JOINS in SQL

Tags: sql

I was asked the below SQL question in an interview. Kindly explain how it works and what join it is.

Q: There are two tables: table emp contains 10 rows and table department contains 12 rows.

```
 Select * from emp,department;
```

What is the result and what join it is?

Comment: If we pass the interview, do we get the job?

Comment: Is this a homework or is this after the interview?

Comment: I wish I had more interview questions like this one!

Comment: "So, how would you join employees by department, if you have those two tables?" *typety typety typety type - click, click* "Well, I'd...hm, eh, let's see..." [obviously reads a wall of text] <- a real phone interview, some moons back; hope this is not similar =/ If not, it's actually a good newbie question. +1.

Answer (score 3):

It would return the Cartesian Product of the two tables, meaning that every combination of `emp` and `department` would be included in the result.

I believe that the next question would be:
Blockquote

> > How do you show the correct department for each employee?

That is, show only the combination of `emp` and `department` where the employee belongs to the department.

This can be done by:

```
SELECT * FROM emp LEFT JOIN department ON emp.department_id=department.id;
```

Assuming that `emp` has a field called `department_id`, and `department` has a matching `id` field (This is quite standard in these type of questions).

The `LEFT JOIN` means that all items from the left side (`emp`) will be included, and each employee will be matched with the corresponding department. If no matching department is found, the resulting fields from `departments` will remain empty. Note that **exactly** 10 rows will be returned.

To show only the employees with valid department IDs, use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. This query will return 0 to 10 rows, depending on the number of matching department ids.

Answer (score 0):

The join you specified is a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join). It will produce one row for each combination of records in the tables being joined.

I'll let you do the math from there.

Answer (score 0):

This will do a cross join I believe, returning 120 rows.  One row for each pair-wise combination of rows from each of the two tables.

All-in-all a fairly useless join most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You will get all rows from both tables with each row joined together.

This is known as a Cartesian join and is very bad.

You will get a total of 120 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is also the old implied syntax (18 yeasr out of date) and accidental cross joins are a common problem with this syntax. One should never use it. Explict joins are a better choice. I would have also mentioned this in an interview and explained why. I also would not have taken the job if they actually used crappy syntax like this because it's very use shows me the database is very likely to be poorly designed.